# HelixToolkit.WPF Additional DependencyProperty not working

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I am creating an application based on one of the example applications in the HelixToolkit (SurfacePlot) found in the ExampleBrwoser.

The SurfacePlotVisual3D class has three dependency properties, I tried to add another one simply by copying/renaming an existing one, but it does not work.

XAML

```
<h:HelixViewport3D ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True" ShowCoordinateSystem="True">
    <local:SurfacePlotVisual3D CurrentX="{Binding CurrentX}" Points="{Binding Data}" ColorValues="{Binding ColorValues}" SurfaceBrush="{Binding SurfaceBrush}" />            
</h:HelixViewport3D>
```

The "CurrentX" property is the one I tried to add.

SurfacePlotVisual3D.cs

```
 public class SurfacePlotVisual3D : ModelVisual3D
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentXProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentX", typeof(double), typeof(SurfacePlotVisual3D),
                                      new UIPropertyMetadata(ModelChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PointsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Points", typeof(Point3D[,]), typeof(SurfacePlotVisual3D),
                                        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, ModelChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorValuesProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ColorValues", typeof(double[,]), typeof(SurfacePlotVisual3D),
                                        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, ModelChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SurfaceBrushProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SurfaceBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(SurfacePlotVisual3D),
                                        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, ModelChanged));
...
...
    public Brush SurfaceBrush
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(SurfaceBrushProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SurfaceBrushProperty, value); }
        }
        public double CurrentX
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(CurrentXProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CurrentXProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void ModelChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((SurfacePlotVisual3D)d).UpdateModel();
        }
```

MainWindow.cs

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
     }
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
  public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       ...
       ...
        public Func<double, double, double> Function { get; set; }
        public Point3D[,] Data { get; set; }
        public double[,] ColorValues { get; set; }
   
        public double CurrentX { get; set; }
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            CurrentX = 6;
            MinX = 0;
            MaxX = 3;
            MinY = -2;
            MaxY = 2;
            Rows = 100;
            Columns = 50;

            Function = (x, y) => Math.Pow(Math.E, (-1) * Math.Pow(y, 2)) * 3*Math.Sin(2*x) + 2;
            ColorCoding = ColorCoding.ByGradientX;
            UpdateModel();
        }
...
...
}
```

I can change "Data", "ColorValues" and "Function" in the MainViewModel and the effect is immediately visible in the plot, but the CurrentX property wont do anything.

Comment: There is no code for instance method UpdateModel. 
First need to understood is it called after update CenterX property in VM.
If no - probably you need specify default value UIPropertyMetadata(default(double), ModelChanged)) when you register CurrentXProperty.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment of Anton suggested the missing default value was the problem.

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentXProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentX", typeof(double), typeof(SurfacePlotVisual3D),
                                      new UIPropertyMetadata((double)0, ModelChanged));
```

This fixed the problem. The (double)0 cast is needed because without it you will get an exception because "object" is not "double" (in my case). So thanks a lot Anton, made my day!